# How do I trigger a macro ("macro1") in a gsheet by putting an "x" into one specific cell on the sheet (i.e. cell A1)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, eventtrigger, google-sheets-macros

I have recorded a macro in a sheet that I want to be able to run from my mobile phone. I understand I will need to create a trigger (onEdit (e)) for a specific cell in order for google sheets to run the macro in the cloud. I have no coding knowledge, only excel. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You could use a checkbox to cause an on edit event.

Answer (score 0):

**Enter x in A1 to run macro1**

```
function onEdit(e) {//Don't forget the e
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName();
  if(e.range.getA1Notation()=='A1' && e.value.toLowerCase()=='x') {
    e.range.setValue('');//this will reset the value so that it will be ready to accepts another lower case x immediately.
    e.source.toast('Hello World.');//You can remove this. It just lets you know that it has run
    macro1();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I still wasn't able to make it work. There is an error when I run it in line 3 (var name=sh...). Also, where in this script is it running "macro1"?

Comment: Okay.  I made it about as simple as I know how.  If you have any errors then write them down completely and show me exactly what your code looks like.